# K-fold in R, how do I store after each iteration?

Tags: r, iteration

If i want to save the testData and trainData after each iteration in R, how would I be able to so?

```
#Create 10 equally size folds
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(cre_card)),breaks=10,labels=FALSE)

#Perform 10 fold cross validation
for(i in 1:10){
    #Segement your data by fold using the which() function 
    testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
    testData <- cre_card[testIndexes, ]
    trainData <- cre_card[-testIndexes, ]
    #Use the test and train data partitions however you desire...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose you to use lists to store all of your sets.

You can use the following code.

```
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(cre_card)),breaks=10,labels=FALSE)
test_sets <- list()
train_sets <- list()
#Perform 10 fold cross validation
for(i in 1:10){
  #Segement your data by fold using the which() function 
  testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
  testData <- cre_card[testIndexes, ]
  trainData <- cre_card[-testIndexes, ]
  #Use the test and train data partitions however you desire...
  test_sets <- c(test_sets,list(testData))
  train_sets <- c(train_sets,list(trainData))
}
```

Then you can use your ith pair of train/test datasets with `test_sets[[i]]` and `train_sets[[i]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the modelr-package you can do the following:

```
require(modelr)
dat <- cars
kcv <- crossv_kfold(dat, k = 10)
```

`kcv` now looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
           train           test   .id
          <list>         <list> <chr>
1 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>    01
2 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>    02
...
```

To train a model you can do:

```
models <- lapply(kcv$train, function(x) lm(dist ~ speed, data = x))
```

Using the `rmse` function from the `modelr`-Package you can calculate the rmse as follows:

```
unlist(Map(rmse, models, kcv$test))
```

P.S.: This example is based on `?modelr::crossv_kfold`